# Why does typeof val === 'object' && val.constructor === Array fail if val created in other frame?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof

Quoting Crockford in JavaScript The Good Parts:

> We can ... define our own is_array function:

```
var is_array = function (value) {
    return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Array;
}
```

> Unfortunately, it fails to identify arrays that were constructed in a different Windows or frame.

And then he doesn't explain why.  So!  Why?

Comment: I believe it is the third condition that fails. Since each `window.Array !== otheframe.Array`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - So is the gist that a non-frame window's Array constructor is not the same as one from a frame (iframe)? Or that *every* frame's Array constructor is specific to that frame?

Comment: @JaredFarrish *every* frame has its own constructor

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Hmm. I wonder why... `:P`

Comment: @ExplosionPills - That was going to be my guess. Makes sense.